# Configurar Subdominios en Namecheap con AWS y nic.ar

Tags: aws, dominio, amazon-s3, subdominio

quisiera saber si alguien me puede guiar con la administración de mi dominio .com.ar estoy utilizando namecheap con un CNAME que apunta a cualquier subdominio de mi dominio principal y un ALIAS que apunta el dominio principal al endpoint de un sitio web alojado en Amazon S3.
Lo que necesito hacer es apuntar los subdominios mail.dominio.com.ar (bucket email) , panel.dominio.com.ar (bucket panel), [www.dominio.com.ar](http://www.dominio.com.ar) y dominio.com.ar (bucket pagina de inicio), subdomino_variable.dominio.com.ar (bucket para subdominios variables).saludos y gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.